# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'keras'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Loading CIFAR-10 dataset using the code below initially works.

```
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = tf.keras.datasets.cifar10.load_data()
```

However, after installing `Keras` to the Environment, running the above line results in the error:

```
>>> AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'keras'
```

My solution was to use the Keras CIFAR-10 load module instead:

```
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = cifar10.load_data()
```

I want to understand why pip installing Keras messes up the `tf.keras` package.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably running an older version of tensorflow which predates tf.keras. Update your tensorflow version.